# Accessing object generated within a list

Tags: python, oop, list-comprehension

So i've been practicing with OOP in python and decided to take a program i wrote before and update it using OOP methodology. Basically it's a game where it will ask you how many players you are playing with, and generate a list using comprehension and display it as the scoreboard. I'm now using OOP to run all of the player turn commands, and am trying to generate multiple player objects using list comprehension.

The code used to generate players is as follows:

```
player_amount = int(input("How many players would you like to play with? "))
max_points = int(input("How many points would you like to play to? "))
scoreboard = [0 for _ in range(player_amount)]
players = [pg.Player for _ in range(player_amount)]
```

The issue code is the next block where i try to access them in order to run the playerTurn command:

```
while max(scoreboard) < max_points:
        for i in players:

            print(f"Player {players.index(i) + 1}'s turn!")

            if input("Would you like to roll? ") != 'y':
                players[i].updateTotal()
                scoreboard[i] = players[i].total_score
            else:
                players[i].playerTurn()
```

Using this code i can see that the list actually generates and stores multiple objects from my Player class, but when it comes to accessing and manipulating them i'm having issues.

Comment: What is your question? Which issues do you have?

Comment: Is it more clear if you do `for player in players:` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1: Creating Player Objects
In the line players = [pg.Player for _ in range(player_amount)], you're not actually creating new Player instances; you're storing the Player class itself in the list multiple times. To create new instances, you should call the constructor, like so: players = [pg.Player() for _ in range(player_amount)].

Issue 2: Accessing Player Objects in Loop
In the loop, you're using i as the object itself, not the index. This is causing the issue in lines like players[i].updateTotal() and scoreboard[i] = players[i].total_score.

```
player_amount = int(input("How many players would you like to play with? "))
```

max_points = int(input("How many points would you like to play to? "))
scoreboard = [0 for _ in range(player_amount)]

## Create Player instances

players = [pg.Player() for _ in range(player_amount)]

while max(scoreboard) < max_points:
for i, player in enumerate(players):

```
    print(f"Player {i + 1}'s turn!")

    if input("Would you like to roll? ") != 'y':
        player.updateTotal()
        scoreboard[i] = player.total_score
    else:
        player.playerTurn()
```

Here are the key changes:

Instances of Player are created using pg.Player() in the players list.
The enumerate function is used in the for loop to get both the index i and the Player object player.